# Charged Particle in a Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism

Can a charged particle move on a imaginary sphere's surface with appropriate conditions? I'have obtained a solution like $(x-at)^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ for a particle's path in a magnetic field. Am I commenting wrong on that result?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? From what is currently given it seems difficult to provide an answer/accurately understand what exactly it is you're asking. Thanks!

Comment: A small particle with charge +q and mass m is injected into a uniform magnetic field $B=b_0(i+j)/\sqrt2$ with an initial velocity $v=v_0(2i+k)/\sqrt5$. i, j, k are unit vectors.

Comment: Maybe edit the post and write the  details there

Comment: I'm afraid, it will be like "solve my question".

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the velocity of the charged particle into two components.
One parallel to the magnetic field and the other component at right angles to the magnetic field.
The component at right angles to the magnetic field will produce a constant Lorentz force on the charged particle which will cause a centripetal acceleration of the charged particle resulting in circular motion.
Superimposed on that circular motion will the a constant translation motion resulting in the charged particle undergoing a helical motion.

You might find that drawing a 3D sketch will help you?

Comment: I've started with this for F, for the initial conditions above.                                                                              \begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\ 
v_x& v_y & v_z \\ 
b_0/\sqrt2 & b_0/\sqrt2 & 0
\end{vmatrix}

Comment: Start with the initial condition for the velocity and from that you can work out the radius, period and the pitch of the helical motion. Also put $b_ov_o/\sqrt{10}$ outside your determinate to make life easier.